# How to send email to email address existing in database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using vb.net and asp.net. I want to send a simple text to email address which existing in my database. I already declare the text and can get the email address from my database. But I don't know how to send the text to that specific email address.Please help. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this VB.Net function:

```
Public Shared Function sendmail(ByVal to As String, ByVal subject As String, ByVal body As String, ByVal IsBodyHtml As Boolean) As Integer

    Dim mm As New MailMessage("registration@yourdomain.org", to)

    mm.Subject = subject
    mm.Body = body
    mm.IsBodyHtml = IsBodyHtml

    Dim smtp As New SmtpClient
    Try
        smtp.Send(mm)
        Return 1
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return 0
    End Try

End Function
```

On your web.config:

```
<configuration>
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp from="registration@yourdomain.org">
    <network  host="smtp.youremailservice.com"
              userName="registration@yourdomain.org"
              password="yourpassword"/>
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```